# How to check if file exists in config folder in Laravel 6?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 6, I have created a constants.php file in config folder and have my static data in that file. I want to check if file exists before using it to avoid runtime errors using the following code in vain:

```
if (file_exists('config/constants.php')) {
    return 'exists';
} else {
    return 'does not exist';
}
```

This code returns 'does not exist'. Please help me on checking existence of file in config folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [config_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-config-path) helper such as:

```php
if (file_exists(config_path('constants.php'))) {
    return 'exists';
} else {
    return 'does not exist';
}
```